# A new statement was found in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Converting Xenforo to IP.Board was not completely successful due to some custom bbcodes, so I have to convert them by hand.

I currently have this in the column:

```
<div style="margin-left:25px;">[video=youtube;0ClLwdqRdo8]</div>
        <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?" rel="external nofollow"></a>
        <div style="margin-left:25px;"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?" rel="external nofollow">http://www.youtube.com/watch?</a></div>
        <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?" rel="external nofollow"></a><div style="margin-left:25px;"> v=0ClLwdqRdo8 </div></div><p></p>
```

and I would like it to become

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ClLwdqRdo8
```

so i did:

```
UPDATE xipb_forums_posts 
REPLACE(post, '<div style=\"text-align:center;\"><p></p><div style=\"margin-left:25px;\">\[video=youtube;\.([a-zA-Z0-9])\]</div><a href=\"http://www.youtube.com/watch?\" rel=\"external nofollow\"></a><div style=\"margin-left:25px;\"><a href=\"http://www.youtube.com/watch?\" rel=\"external nofollow\">http://www.youtube.com/watch?</a></div><a href=\"http://www.youtube.com/watch?\" rel=\"external nofollow\"></a><div style=\"margin-left:25px;\"> v=0ClLwdqRdo8 </div></div><p></p>', 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$1') 
WHERE pid = '68542';
```

but it returns me error:

> A new statement was found, but there is no delimiter between this new
> statement and the previous one. (near "REPLACE" at position 25)
> Unexpected token. (near "," at position 37)

Where am I wrong? initially I thought he regarded [as an expression

Comment: Why not use `SET` instead of `REPLACE` here? `REPLACE` is a function that returns data, so you aren't actually doing anything in your SQL. In fact, you likely don't need replace AT ALL. Just `SET post = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ClLwdqRdo8'` instead of the `REPLACE` line.

Comment: Additionally, good call storing specific dynamic data in your database instead of a bunch of constant markup. You could of course optimize this even more by only including the video ID in that column, instead of the youtube link. For example, `0ClLwdqRdo8` instead of `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ClLwdqRdo8` (assuming the links are always to youtube videos)

Answer (score 1):

`REPLACE()` is function that returns a string and does not affect by itself alone the rows of the table.

If the pattern is always like your sample data where `'$1'`needs to be replaced by the string after `'[video=youtube;'` and before `']'`:

```
UPDATE xipb_forums_posts 
SET post = REPLACE(
             'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$1',
             '$1',
             SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(post, '[video=youtube;', -1), ']', 1)
           )
WHERE pid = '68542';
```

Comment: yes, but if in `[video=youtube; 0ClLwdqRdo8]`, `$1` should put `0ClLwdqRdo8`, how do I tell what `$1` equals

Comment: It works, but so it replaces the whole column for me, and not just the piece I want. Imagine an article: "blah blah [video] blah blah", he now put me "[video]" and removed the "blah blah", thanks for the help

Comment: @LegoLiam In your question you say that you want `<div style="margin-left:25px;....` to become `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ClLwdqRdo8`. This is what my code does. Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=4170a443539b3680b8be325b272fa86e